# Sending Email to two email addresses - Ajax/Php

Tags: php, email

Hello I am trying to send an email via a contact forum to two email addresses one of the email addresses is mine and the other is the email that has been typed into the email input

For some reason it is grabbing my servers email and not the email I am putting into the input field 
So for example I type "Emma@SomeEmail.co.uk" into the input field and for some reason it will say in the email I receive that it has been sent to my email and "@srv17.main-hosting.eu" instead of sending to my email and "Emma@SomeEmail.co.uk"

Could someone please see what is going wrong? here is some of the code:

```
$to_Email       = "MyEmail@ze.co.uk, '$user_Email'";

if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }


    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage" ], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message . "\r\n\n"  .'Hello '.$user_Name.' We will contact you as soon as possible about your query.' ."\n". 'You can find your reference number in the email subject.' ."\n". 'Thank you.'. "\r\n\n" .'-- '.$user_Email, $headers);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should `"MyEmail@ze.co.uk, '$user_Email'";` just be `"MyEmail@ze.co.uk, $user_Email";`? Not sure about the other email address.. might be a default setup on your server?

Comment: You're not setting `$user_Email` until *after* you've already defined `$to_Email`...

Comment: Your defining `$to_Email` before you have created the variable `$user_Email`

Comment: A suggestion, if things don't work as expected, don't suppress errors with `@`. Error messages can usually point you in the right direction... and turning on `display_errors` while developing is also a good idea (that should have thrown a PHP notice about using an undefined variable, for example).

Comment: `'$user_Email'` - Variables don't get parse in single quotes; you can safely remove those.

Comment: I'm so stupid thanks guys

Comment: @ChrisLad Don't be so hard on yourself. It's the "stupid" ones that don't ask questions ;-) just a wee bit of an error, that's all; it happens.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That will get parsed, because it's in double-quotes, though...

Comment: @moopet You're right, my (slight) mistake. However, that will produce `MyEmail@ze.co.uk, 'email@example.com'` which stands to fail in headers for the single quotes.